# Trying to make a live /proc/ reader using bash script for live process monitoring

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Im trying to make a little side project script to sit and monitor all of the /proc/ directories, for the most part I have the concept running and it works(to a degree). What im aiming for here is to scan through all the files and cat their status files and pull out the appropriate info, and then I would like to run this process in an infinite loop to give me live updates of when something is running on and dropping off of the scheduler. Right now every time you run the script, it will print 50+ blank lines and every single time it hits the proper regex it will print it correctly, but Im aiming for it to not roll down the screen the way it does. Any help at all would be appreciated.

`````
regex="[0-9]"
temp=""
for f in /proc/*; do
       if [[ -d $f && $f =~ /proc/$regex ]]; then
                output=$(cat $f/status | grep "^State") #> /dev/null
                process_id=$(cut -b 7- <<< $f)
                state=$(cut -b 10-19 <<< $output)
                tabs 4
                if [[ $state =~ "(running)" ]]; then
                echo -e "$process_id:$state\n" | sort >> temp
                fi
        fi
done
cat temp
rm temp````
`````

Comment: The `tabs` command will output a blank line or two. Did you intend to put that in your script, or was it meant to be a `:tabs` command for your editor?

Answer (score 0):

To get the PID and status of running all processes, try:

```
awk -F':[[:space:]]*' '/State:/{s=$2} /Pid:/{p=$2} ENDFILE{if (s~/running/) print p,s; p="X"; s="X"}' OFS=: /proc/*/status
```

To get this output updated every second:

```
while sleep 1; do awk -F':[[:space:]]*' '/State:/{s=$2} /Pid:/{p=$2} ENDFILE{if (s~/running/) print p,s; p="X"; s="X"}' OFS=: /proc/*/status; done
```